# Run a function in python when you have the function name as a string

Tags: python

**Example**

I have a test.py with this one function

```py
def hello():
    print("hello, world")
```

**Problem**

I want to import this module in another module, and then run the script. However, the module will be given as command line argument and thus I have to execute the function only knowing the name of the function as a string. How can I execute it?

**What I want to do**

python/pseudocode

```py
def main():
    import test
    function_name = "hello"
    run code test["hello"]()
```

**Things I have tried**

- Envoking the function through the modules locals(), but I haven't found a way to make it work.
- reading the module as string and using exec. However, I don't want to parse the whole module to find its functions etc

Any help is appreciated

Comment: For a *sane* implementation you'd make a map from user input to functions, e.g. `{'hello': hello}[input]()`…

Comment: Thank you for your input. I still need to be able to execute my function only having the name of the function stored as a string

Comment: Redefine test.py:
```
def hello(text):
    print(f"{text}, world")
```
And then use the calling script as follows:
```
def main():
    function_name = __import__('test').hello
    function_name("hello")


main()
```
Returning:
```
hello, world
```

Comment: Have you tried using `eval()`? It would be like `eval("test.hello()")`.

Comment: @Jortega Never use `eval`, especially if it involves *user input*. `getattr(test, function_name)()` works just fine.

Comment: I doesn't solve my problem since I only have the function name as string. I would need to run `function_name =  __import__('test').'hello'` somehow

Comment: Thanks @Jortega, I will try that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Read the duplicates and my previous two comments. You have been staring the solution in the face the entire time. Don't use `eval`.

Comment: @deceze Thanks! getattr() solved my problem beautifully.